# Seaborn box plot cut off on graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm making a box plot with seaborn that's put into a log scale. However, the lower ends of the graph seem to be cut off, turning it into a visual nightmare.

```
print(labels_df)
```

```
           date  actuals   predicted  winter  spring  summer  fall
0    2016-01-01    400.0  397.964975       1       0       0     0
1    2016-01-02    200.0  307.744056       1       0       0     0
2    2016-01-03    300.0  456.017753       1       0       0     0
3    2016-01-04    300.0  752.516418       1       0       0     0
4    2016-01-05    400.0  449.730626       1       0       0     0
...         ...      ...         ...     ...     ...     ...   ...
1822 2020-12-27    100.0  250.694625       1       0       0     0
1823 2020-12-28    250.0  261.378071       1       0       0     0
1824 2020-12-29    333.0  339.160428       1       0       0     0
1825 2020-12-30    385.0  433.712262       1       0       0     0
1826 2020-12-31    154.0  558.770808       1       0       0     0

[1827 rows x 7 columns]
```

```
plot_data_2016 = labels_df[labels_df['date'].dt.year == 2016]

# reverse one-hot encoding
plot_data_2016['season'] = (plot_data_2016.iloc[:, 2:] == 1).idxmax(1)

# actuals and predicted to one column
plot_data_2016=plot_data_2016.melt(id_vars='season', value_vars=['actuals','predicted'], value_name='ecoli_value')

ax=sn.boxplot(x='season', y='ecoli_value', hue='variable', data=plot_data_2016, palette="Set3", linewidth=1)

ax.set_title('Repentigny 2016')
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_ylim(ymin=0)
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
```

[image]

How can I fix this?

EDIT: When I remove `ax.set_ylim(ymin=0)`, it doesn't change the graph.

```
plot_data_2016 = labels_df[labels_df['date'].dt.year == 2016]

# reverse one-hot encoding
plot_data_2016['season'] = (plot_data_2016.iloc[:, 2:] == 1).idxmax(1)

# actuals and predicted to one column
plot_data_2016 = plot_data_2016.melt(id_vars='season', value_vars=['actuals','predicted'], value_name='ecoli_value')

ax=sn.boxplot(x='season', y='ecoli_value', hue='variable', data=plot_data_2016, palette="Set3", linewidth=1)

ax.set_title('Repentigny 2016')
ax.set_yscale('log')
#ax.set_ylim(ymin=0)
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
```

[image]

EDIT2: There are no negative values in the data frame.

```
print(plot_data_2016)
```

```
     season   variable  ecoli_value
0    winter    actuals   400.000000
1    winter    actuals   200.000000
2    winter    actuals   300.000000
3    winter    actuals   300.000000
4    winter    actuals   400.000000
..      ...        ...          ...
727  winter  predicted  1605.692714
728  winter  predicted   587.054679
729  winter  predicted  1084.856463
730  winter  predicted  1513.211905
731  winter  predicted  2049.604786

[732 rows x 3 columns]
```

```
print(plot_data_2016[plot_data_2016['ecoli_value'] < 0])
```

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [season, variable, ecoli_value]
Index: []
```

Comment: Don't set `ax.set_ylim(ymin=0)`

Comment: It doesn't help

Comment: Please check your data:  negative values will not be displayed on log scale axis

Comment: You cannot input negative values to a logarithm.

Comment: There are no negative values

Comment: Note also that `log(0) = -inf`

Comment: have you had a look what they look like using `matplotlib.pyplot.box()`? If both libraries are doing it then its probably a data issue.

Comment: Ok, it turns out that there are 362 rows with `ecoli_value` = 0

Comment: Also note that the logarithm of anything less than 1 maps to values below 0.

Comment: Did you try setting the log scale before creating the boxplot? `plt.yscale('log')`? Or `ax.set_ylim(ymin=1e-5)` ?

Comment: What is the output of `plot_data_2016['ecoli_value'].desccribe()`? If your Q1 (25%) is 0, there is no way that the plot can be fixed using `set_ylim`.  You may want to transform the data using `log(ecoli_value+1)`

Comment: Try using `ax.set_yscale('symlog')`